# UPDATE trigger function - SQL Server - Postgres equivalent

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-trigger

SQL Server has this UPDATE function which one can use in triggers and which tells you whether a given column is part of the update/insert statement or not.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/update-trigger-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Does PostgreSQL have a logically equivalent function or any other way of checking this? Note that a logical check like `old value <> new value` is not what I need. Some update statements which I have contain code like

```
UPDATE table 
set 
col1 = col1
WHERE ...
```

and that has been done for a reason. I cannot easily change this.
So a logical check like `old value <> new value` would not work for me.

So I am looking just for an equivalent function in Postgres.

Comment: There is no such function in Postgres. And to be honest, I would question the design of a system that relies on this. Why isn't it enough to detect a change on the column value?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I question the design too. But that's how it is. Don't ask me please :) Now we are migrating to Postgres and we can redesign it of course... but first I wanted to try to do it with minimal changes i.e. just by translating it logically equivalently to Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

You can try if specifying the column in the event of the trigger works for you.

```
CREATE TRIGGER reggirt
               BEFORE UPDATE OF nmuloc
                      ON elbat
               EXECUTE FUNCTION noitcnuf();
```

Note the `OF ...` after the `UPDATE`.

The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) says:

> For `UPDATE` events, it is possible to specify a list of columns using this syntax:
>
> ```
> UPDATE OF column_name1 [, column_name2 ... ]
> ```
>
> The trigger will only fire if at least one of the listed columns is mentioned as a target of the `UPDATE` command.

Sounds like it could do what you want.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. Is that the closest I can get in Postgres (to what I have in SQL Server) ? I guess it is.

Comment: Tried it but it's not quite what I wanted... Seems there's no way to do it in Postgres.